# How to create uiscrollview with custom shapes in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ipod

I want to create custom view with image which can be scrollable and visible in only shape i created (i.e. triangle, oval, ect.) 
 I have tried UIBezierPath but its only mask the layer of imageview but i want same as in UIScrollView so image is also scrollable.
I want to perform this operation as quick as possible,Please suggest me the technique or example how to do it. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Any view you place on the scrollview is scrollable, so you can create a custom class that creates UIImages from your bezier paths then add those to the scrollview in UIImageViews

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I would do. I just tried this out and it works. All you need to do is add a mask to the view that contains the scroll view as a subview. (`self` in this case is the view itself.)

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectInset(self.frame, 5, 5) cornerRadius:50.0f].CGPath;
self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Here's a gist from my working code: https://gist.github.com/rcdilorenzo/6437136

Comment: @Christian Di Lorenzo Is there any way to apply gradient color to the boundary of UIScrollView masklayer? I craeted shape layer on UIScrollView and when i apply gradient mask to that scrollview the former shape disappear.

Comment: @RajeshMaurya: So you want to have the scroll view have a gradient background or the outside part of the scroll view?

Comment: @ChristianDiLorenzo I just want to have gradient along the border of scrollview. Mins making UIBezierPath with gradient color.

Comment: @RajeshMaurya: You'll need to do the mask and border separately. I'd recommend some searching on gradient borders and then add the gradient layer directly as a sub-layer of the scroll view.